# Is OpenStreetMaps's Nominatim "Centre Point" the centroid and what EPSG is it?

Tags: openstreetmap, epsg, nominatim, web-mercator

I looked up a couple of places on OpenStreetMap's [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/), like [Bruck an der Mur](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=3904390&class=boundary), and I could not confirm whether the reported coordinates are indeed the same thing as the centroid, and which EPSG is used. I recall that Web Mercator ([EPSG:3857](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857)) is used for online mapping tools, such Google Maps and OpenStreetMaps. However, given that this "Centre Point" is lat-lon, I am inclined to believe it's EPSG:4326.

What is the correct one?

Comment: In your example there is a [point](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/34855256)  representing the town center, which is listed at the bottom of the page under "Linked Places". This coordinate is the one reported as the center point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nominatim is using OpenStreetMap data and the boundary of Bruck an der Mur is this OSM relation https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3904390.
The named place is this OSM point https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/34855256. It is not computed by the boundary as centroid or point on surface but the OSM mapper "JM82" has placed the town centre just there. The source data as XML reveals the latest editor as well as that natively the coordinates are stored into the OSM database as latitudes and longitudes.

```
<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.8.5 (2187694 spike-08.openstreetmap.org)" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/">
<node id="34855256" visible="true" version="9" changeset="59510747" timestamp="2018-06-03T14:44:55Z" user="JM82" uid="2641694" lat="47.4121987" lon="15.2721668">
<tag k="name" v="Bruck an der Mur"/>
<tag k="name:hu" v="Bruck an der Mur"/>
<tag k="name:ru" v="Брук-ан-дер-Мур"/>
<tag k="place" v="town"/>
<tag k="population" v="9748"/>
</node>
</osm>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How can I retrieve the boundary in the first link? And, sorry if that is naïve, lat-lon means EPSG:4326 right?

Comment: Knowing the history of OpenStreetMap the definition of the coordinate system is probably "as GPS shows them" thus practically EPSG:4326. But the main OSM database is using just latitude and longitude https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/db/structure.sql. Find the boundary from your own Nominatim link, from line `OSM relation 3904390`.

Comment: I am afraid I do not get what you mean by "Find the boundary from your own Nominatim link, from line `OSM relation 3904390`". I believe I arrive at the right page (here: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3904390#map=13/47.4036/15.2571) but then I would not know how to, say, download these boundaries as geojson/shp/esri... Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you did not find the link to the relation. In https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3904390#map=13/47.4036/15.2571 there is a download link for the relation in the bottom left, pointing to https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/3904390. But that is only a list of linestrings "ways" which all together make the boundary. OSM data is a bit complicated. Maybe reading https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example helps you further.